# JFileChooser Event

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Looking to get the current file path so need to catch an event when there is a value change in the "Look In:" combobox in the JFileChooser below. I would like to fire the same event when the folder is selected from the list so I can keep updating the file path.

[image: JFileChooser]

I'm not looking for the event when the Open of Cancel buttons are pressed!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you change the folder in the `"Look in:"` combo box, only one [`PropertyChangeEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html) is fired with the property name: [`JFileChooser.DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY).

You can use this little code sample to test what property change events are fired in the background when you click around in the `JFileChooser`:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Prop Change Event: " + evt.getPropertyName());
        if (JFileChooser.DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY.equals(
                    evt.getPropertyName())) {
            // This is the event you're looking for
        }
    }
});
```

Note though that changing the current folder in the `"Look in:"` combo box is not the only event that generates a `PropertyChangeEvent` with property name `DIRECTORY_CHANGED_PROPERTY`, for example if you double click on a folder in the file list, that also generates this event (amongst other events like [`SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY)).